# Custom Spring annotation not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-aop

I'm trying out a simple custom Spring annotation, but it seems like Spring isn't executing anything when i slap the annotation on a method...anyone have any ideas? I see no logging at all. Maybe i need some aop dependency?

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LethargicLoggerAspect {
   private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

   @Around("@annotation(LethargicLogger)")
   public Object logSlowExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint 
                                       proceedingJoinPoint) throws 
                                                              Throwable {
      log.error("HIIIIIIIIII david");

      Object proceed = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();

      return proceed;
    }

}



@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LethargicLogger {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks good, you need to add `package` to the `@Around` annotation.

```
@Around("@annotation(com.example.package.LethargicLogger)")
   public Object logSlowExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint 
                                       proceedingJoinPoint) throws 
                                                              Throwable {
}
```

Comment: got it figured out....the annotation was on a method that was getting called from the same class

Comment: This would be a duplicate of many other questions then. I suggest you delete the question. And do add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question next time: aspect + intercepted application classes including package names(!) + configuration. Otherwise nobody can see what is going on, people have to guess.